# Primefaces wizard is resetting the values on click of back button

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a strange problem with primefaces wizard component. When I click next button on entering some values in the first tab,it goes to the next tab fine. There I entered some values and clicked on back button ,here comes the problem,I moved to the first tab,and again If I click the next button ,entered values are resetting to null.

I am posting the code below.

```
  <p:tab id="personal" title="Personal">

     <p:panel header="Personal Details">

        <h:messages errorClass="error"/>

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value" styleClass="grid">
           <h:outputText value="Firstname: *" />
           <p:inputText required="true" label="productName"
                 value="#{product.productName}" />

           <h:outputText value="Lastname: *" />
           <p:inputText required="true" label="productName"
                 value="#{product.loggedInUserName}" />


        </h:panelGrid>
     </p:panel>
  </p:tab>

  <p:tab id="address" title="Address">
     <p:panel header="Adress Details">
```

```
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value" styleClass="grid">
           <h:outputText value="Firstname: " />
           <p:inputText label="updateName"
                 value="#{product.updateName}" />

           <h:outputText value="Lastname:" />
           <p:inputText  label="error"
                 value="#{product.error}" />


        </h:panelGrid>

     </p:panel>
  </p:tab>

  <p:tab id="contact" title="Contact">
     <p:panel header="Contact Information">

        <h:messages errorClass="error"/>

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value" styleClass="grid">
           <h:outputText value="Firstname: *" />
           <p:inputText required="true" label="majorVersion"
                 value="#{product.majorVersion}" />

           <h:outputText value="Lastname: *" />
           <p:inputText required="true" label="minorVersion"
                 value="#{product.minorVersion}" />

        </h:panelGrid>            
     </p:panel>
  </p:tab>

  <p:tab id="confirm" title="Confirmation">
     <p:panel header="Confirmation">
        <h:messages errorClass="error"/>

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value" styleClass="grid">
           <h:outputText value="Firstname:" />
           <p:inputText label="buildVersion"
                 value="#{product.buildVersion}" />

           <h:outputText value="Lastname:" />
           <p:inputText  label="productRevision"
                 value="#{product.productRevision}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
     </p:panel>
  </p:tab>
```

Any suggestions greately appreciated.

Comment: What is the scope of managed bean `product` ?

Comment: please first check your managed bean has bean created properly

Answer (score 0):

check your managed bean has been created properly